# "Save as..." menu item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write code for "Save as..." menu item. My code looks like this:

```
private void menuItem9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = ".XML file (*.xml)|*.xml";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

    string fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
    document.Save(fileName+ ".xml");
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        File.Create(fileName);
    }
}
```

So basically what I want to do is working "save as" option. After clicking on it, I want to be able to save my .xml file with different name in any place I want.

Comment: What's not working? From memory your code looks ok, are you getting a particular error?

Comment: After saveFileDialog is closing, something like "XML file is wrong. Document has no main element" appears.

Comment: That's because your XML document is empty. Before you save it, you have to put something in it.

Comment: Also, the `if (!File.Exists(fileName))...` part is unnecessary. `XmlDocument.Save` creates a file if it doesn't exist, and if it _didn't_, creating the file after you call `document.Save()` sure isn't going to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will throw an exception since your `XmlDocument` contains no root node. Also keep in mind that `SaveFileDialog's` `Filename` property also contains the extension.

You can either create a new file without a Root node using

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = ".XML file (*.xml)|*.xml";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{  
    File.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

or by making sure your XmlDocument has a root node before saving it:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = ".XML file (*.xml)|*.xml";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("Root"));
    document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, you can find more information on how to use the XmlDocument class [here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/)

Answer (score 0):

Your newly created instance of `XmlDocument` document does not have any root element, Hence the `XmlException`

You can avoid using `saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()` as `saveFileDialog1.FileName` is already a string value.

This code

```
document.Save(fileName+ ".xml");
```

should be

```
document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void menuItem9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = ".XML file (*.xml)|*.xml";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

    //Add this line of code
    document.LoadXml("<root></root>");

    string fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
    // Save the document to a file
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName,null);
    document.Save(writer);

}
```